# C# - how do i get last bios time?

Tags: c#, winapi, bios

Hello i need to get the last bios time in my c# application.
(not the current bios date or last boot date, but the bios time from task manager)

[image: the bios time im looking for (ref image)]

is this information saved in registry? how exactly can i achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's stored in the registry, here in this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power
```

in this value `FwPOSTTime`, in milliseconds.

For example:

[image]

[image]